# Writing List of tuple into a file in Scala

Tags: scala

I have some data in a variable called `windData` with information below.

```
ListBuffer((2001-01-01T00:00:00.000+01:00,578,WIND projekt GmbH),
(2001-01-01T01:00:00.000+01:00,420,WIND projekt GmbH),....)
```

I need to write this data to csv file.
Code I have written

```
def printToFile(f: java.io.File)(op: java.io.PrintWriter => Unit) {
    val p = new java.io.PrintWriter(f)
    try { op(p) } finally { p.close() }
  }
 printToFile(new File("/Users/krishna/Experiment/Internship/wind.csv")) { p =>
    windData.foreach(p.println)
  }
```

Output

```
(2001-01-01T00:00:00.000+01:00,578,WIND projekt GmbH)
(2001-01-01T01:00:00.000+01:00,420,WIND projekt GmbH)
```

Expected Output:

```
2001-01-01T00:00:00.000+01:00,578,WIND projekt GmbH
2001-01-01T01:00:00.000+01:00,420,WIND projekt GmbH
```

How to I get rid of the tuple before and after in a line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This would work for list of Tuples of any length - using `productIterator.mkString(",")` to serialize the Tuple into a String without accessing each field explicitly:

```
printToFile(new File("/tmp/wind.csv")) { p =>
  windData.foreach(tuple => p.println(tuple.productIterator.mkString(",")))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example:

```
scala> val d = ListBuffer((1,2,3),(4,5,6))
d: scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer[(Int, Int, Int)] = ListBuffer((1,2,3), (4,5,6))

scala> d.foreach(x => print(x._1 + "," +  x._2 + "," +  x._3 + "\n"))
```

Result:

```
1,2,3
4,5,6
```

Comment: You can also provide a partial function inside `foreach`, for readability: `foreach { case (first, second) => print....`

Answer (score 0):

You can do

```
windData.foreach { tuple => 
  println(tuple._1)
  println(tuple._2) 
}
```

Comment: I still see the same problem.

Comment: This will give you back a tuple since you are using the comma operator.